# installing rhel/centos/fedora on a dell inspiron 17R laptop

Tags: linux, centos, dell-inspiron, fedora-13, rhel-5

Got a dell inspiron 17R laptop.

Trying to figure out how to install RHEL/Centos 5.5/Fedora 13 on the box.

When using the basic Centos 5.5 liveCD, continously got a repeating error of buffer I/O on the SR0 device..

Tried using the Fedora 13 liveCD, got a hang, in that the splash screen never completed the fedora symbol...

Also tried to do the Fedora liveCD boot, using the boot options of "noprobe text", no difference.

Not much from searching via google on this issue.

Thoughts/comments on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `continously got a repeating error of buffer I/O on the SR0 device` -  seems like a bad CD or a bad drive